# I want to read the xml sub sub sub node name and value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any friends help on this.
**Now I want to read a complete path when I get a value.**

I want to read the name of  parent node, sub node, sub sub node and so on in XML using C#. 
And I don't know the any node name before. kindly help if possible

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Element xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/AML/CaseInvestigationMangement/Moduli/XmlImportControls/xsdBorrow.xsd xsd2009027_kor21.xsd" Kod="370" xmlns="http://localhost/AML/CaseInvestigationMangement/Moduli/XmlImportControls/xsdBorrow.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ANode>
        <BNode>
            <CNode>
                <Example>
                    <Name>John</Name>
                    <NO>001</NO>
                </Example>
            </CNode>
        </BNode>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <Date>2011-10-01</Date>
    </ANode>
    <ANode>
        <BNode>
            <CNode>
                <Example>
                    <Name>Mike</Name>
                    <NO>002</NO>
                </Example>
            </CNode>
        </BNode>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <Date>2011-03-31</Date>
    </ANode>
</Element>
```

I want to read every node one by one like anode, bnode, cnode, Example and then name and NO.
Now I want to read a complete path when I get a value. please help...

Comment: What do you mean by 'node name'? Perhaps you could edit in some XML as an example?

Comment: thanks for ur quick response kindly see the edited once for ur reference..

Comment: search google and you will get many good article to start with. here is one http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

Comment: You're not the first who wants to read specific nodes from XML. Please use the search, and you'll find for example [How do I read an XML with unknown structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908053/how-do-i-read-an-xml-with-unknown-structure) or [Problem in reading XML node with unknown root/parent nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185049/problem-in-reading-xml-node-with-unknown-root-parent-nodes). I accidentally close-voted with the wrong link, but those should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the following method

```
string GetHTMLOutputFromXML()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    XmlTextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        //Get a reader
        reader = new XmlTextReader(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLPath"] + "XMLFile.xml");
        string elementName = "";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //For every node
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                //If you happen upon an element mark down its name
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    elementName = reader.Name;
                    output.Append(elementName + " - ");
                    break;
                //If this is an element, use its value
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    output.Append( reader.Value + "<br/>");
                    break;
            }
            //You could also use the following code to get attribute values
            //if (reader.HasAttributes)
            //    output.Append(reader.GetAttribute("attr") + "<br/>");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        output.Append("Error while reading the xml file");
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the reader.
        reader.Close();
    }


    return output.ToString();
}
```

Using this method on your XML will return

Element - /2001/XMLSchema-instance">
ANode - BNode - CNode - Example - Name - John
NO - 001
ID - 1234
Date - 2011-10-01
ANode - BNode - CNode - Example - Name - Mike
NO - 002
ID - 5678
Date - 2011-03-31

You can change the code to show the results the way you want.

You can also read more concerning basic XML manipulation [here](http://dotnethints.com/blog?id=37)

Comment: Thanks kbadas, I used this and now this is running sucessfully. But can you tell me how to know the path of the element value,attribute or any sub element. from parent node to current value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To do this you will need an extra string variable (which I will call xmlPath). Using it, change the previous code a bit so that it will handle the path in each iteration. In case of Element use xmlPath += reader.Name + " -> "; to create the path. In case of Text output.Append(xmlPath + " - " + reader.Value + "<br/>"); to create the output and in case of EndElement  {string[] xmlPathArray = xmlPath.Split(new string[] { " -> " }, StringSplitOptions.None); xmlPath = "";for (int counter = 0; counter < xmlPathArray.Length - 2; counter++) xmlPath += xmlPathArray[counter] + " -> "; to level up.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read every node one by one...

Then I suggest you try using [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class. The following snippet demonstrates basic usage for reading nodes names and values:

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead("path to your xml file"))
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string indent= string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat(" ", reader.Depth));
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(indent+ reader.Name);
            }
            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(indent+ reader.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
 Element  
 
  /2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  
 ANode  
  BNode  
   CNode  
    Example  
     Name  
      John  
     NO  
      001  
  ID  
   1234  
  Date  
   2011-10-01  
 ANode  
  BNode  
   CNode  
    Example  
     Name  
      Mike  
     NO  
      002  
  ID  
   5678  
  Date  
   2011-03-31
```

---

Hope this helps.