# I want to read complete XML element, value, attribute path

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any friends help on this.
**Now I want to read a complete path when I get a value.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Element xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/AML/CaseInvestigationMangement/Moduli/XmlImportControls/xsdBorrow.xsd xsd2009027_kor21.xsd" Kod="370" xmlns="http://localhost/AML/CaseInvestigationMangement/Moduli/XmlImportControls/xsdBorrow.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ANode>
        <BNode>
            <CNode>
                <Example>
                    <Name>John</Name>
                    <NO>001</NO>
                </Example>
            </CNode>
        </BNode>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <Date>2011-10-01</Date>
    </ANode>
    <ANode>
        <BNode>
            <CNode>
                <Example>
                    <Name>Mike</Name>
                    <NO>002</NO>
                </Example>
            </CNode>
        </BNode>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <Date>2011-03-31</Date>
    </ANode>
</Element>
```

Now I want to read a complete path when I get a value, like NO element then I want to store complete path NO->Example->Cnode->Bnode->Anode. please help...
I have used XMLTextReader to read xml element and value. for more reference please click [I want to read the xml sub sub sub node name and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869333/i-want-to-read-the-xml-sub-sub-sub-node-name-and-value)

Comment: What do you mean "read a complete path"? Do you want to construct XPath to an element/attribute ? (Not sure why you prefer `XmlTextReader` to more friendly `XDocument`, but not my call).

Comment: I want to read all parent to root element name when I found any value..

Answer (score 0):

With xml linq, you can do it as below:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"fileUri");
var paths=doc.Descendants()
             .Where(e=>!(e.HasElements || String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)))
             .Select(e=>e.Name+"->"+
                     String.Join("->",e.Ancestors().Select(a=>a.Name)));
```

Comment: thanks Victor, I am trying to do this but code asking to declare e as xelement. can u please tell me what is e. I have no knoledge of XML link...